# Won't match template function

Tags: c++, templates

In:

```
#include <string>

void f( char const*, char const* = "" ) {
}

template<class StringType1,class StringType2> inline
void g( StringType1 const &s1, StringType2 const &s2 = "" ) {
  f( s1.c_str(), s2.c_str() );
}

template<class StringType> inline
void h( StringType const &s1, StringType const &s2 = "" ) {
  f( s1.c_str(), s2.c_str() );
}

int main() {             
  std::string s;
  g( s ); // error: no matching function for call to ‘g(std::string&)’
  h( s ); // OK
  return 0;
}
```

the compiler doesn't match the call to `g()` because it has 2 template arguments, but it matches `h()` just fine.  Why?

FYI: My codebase actually uses several, highly-specialized string classes, so I want to allow for maximal flexibility where the first and second arguments might be of different string types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has no idea what `StringType2` is supposed to be.  You would need to call it with something like:

```
   g<std::string, std::string>( s );
```

to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

g() is rejected because StringType2 is deduced to be a const char[] (or some similar variant of it) that does not offer the c_str() member method. h() matches fine because you forced StringType to be std::string in both cases.

You will need to look into more detailed metaprogramming techniques, but this should be perfectly possible.

Edit: Apparently default args won't participate in template type deduction, or something. In any case, you will need to use a different technique to accomplish this, like partial specialization.

Comment: I don't think this explanation is correct. AFAIK SFINAE doesn't look into function bodies. Rather, as I discovered not long ago (Johannes helped explain why, but I don't remember), a default for an argument isn't used to deduce template arguments. That is, calling foo() with defaulted argument, say def value 42, is different from calling foo(42), with respect to template arg deduction. It was surprising to me, because I thought of the former as being just rewritten to the latter by the compiler.